# ListView in Fragment saves data but won't re populate on orientation change

Tags: listview, android-fragments

I have a main activity that uses 3 tabs populated by fragments. One of the fragments has a listview that is populated by and `ArrayList<String>`.  The view successfully adds new items via an "add" button and updates as is should.  When I rotate to a different orientation (portrait to landscape OR landscape to portrait - doesn't matter) the listview won't repoplulate.

The data from the `ArrayList` is successfully saved using `onSaveInstanceState` and successfully repopulated into the `ArrayList` in the `onActivityCreated` method (I've also tried it in the `onCreateView` method with the exact same results). The data will NOT repopulate into the `ListView`, however.

Also, while the `ArrayList` is repopulated on the first orientation change, all data is lost on the next orientation change.

Been trying to figure this out for a while now with no luck.  I've posted the code for the fragment below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```java
    public class FragZones extends Fragment {

    public static final String SAVED_ZONE_LIST = "homecontrol.zones";
    private static final int REQ_ZONE_NAME = 0;

    ArrayList<String> listZones;
    ImageButton ibtnAddZone, ibtnRemoveZone;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView lvZones;
    String selectedZone;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedState) {
        //setRetainInstance(true);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_zones, container, false);

        ibtnAddZone = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnAdd);
        ibtnRemoveZone = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnRemove);
        lvZones = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvZones);
        listZones = new ArrayList<String>();

        // set ListView adapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listZones);
        lvZones.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*
         *  On click listeners
         */
        lvZones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position,
                    long mLong) {
                selectedZone = (String) lvZones.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

        });;

        ibtnAddZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addZone();
            }
        });

        ibtnRemoveZone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (selectedZone != null)
                    removeZone(selectedZone);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
        if ( savedState != null){
            String names = "";  // for debugging
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayList<String> listZones = (ArrayList<String>) savedState.getSerializable("zones");
            for (int i = 0; i < listZones.size(); i++){
                names += listZones.get(i).toString()+ "\n";
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),names, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // for debugging
            /*adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listZones);
            lvZones.setAdapter(adapter);*/
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putSerializable("zones", listZones);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to make this work.  First of all, I put the code from `onActivityCreated` and put it back in `onCreateView`.  Basically, I just created a temporary `ArrayList<String>` to put the values in from the savedState Bundle, cleared listZones (and notified adapter - otherwise it didn't work), then copied the values form the temporary array to the listZones array and notified the adapter after each addition (otherwise it wouldn't work). Then I cleared the tempList to free the memory?

```java
    if ( savedState != null){
        ArrayList<String> tempList = (ArrayList<String>) savedState.getSerializeable("zones"));
        listZones.clear();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++){
            listZones.add(tempList.get(i));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        tempList.clear();
    }
```

I have since created a class for each Zone and made it Parcelable to make everything go smoother, but as far as saving and ArrayList this worked well.